# Strange behaviour with Pickers and Forms in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-form

I'm developing an application in SwiftUI to manage a virtual datacenter (servers, firewall rules, load balancers...) The code I attach is an excerpt of the app to show the current problem I'm facing and I was not able to solve by myself.
The problems (or SwiftUI bugs?) are the following:

- a) I cannot select a value in a Picker two times
- b) Strange behaviour when I try to hide some fields in my Form

The way to replicate this problems with the code attached is the following:

1. Run the application
2. Go to the tab Create
3. Click on Firewall Policy to create a new one
4. Click on picker Protocol and change the value (e.g. UDP)
5. Try to change the value again (e.g. TCP). Then, problem a) appears. Picker shows as "selected" but it doesn't work
6. Go to the picker Action and change value to Deny, then some rows in the form are hidden (expected behaviour)
7. Now, try to change the picker Action again to Allow, then b) problem appears, I get a strange view change and a blank screen

I'm running this with Xcode 11.3 on MacOS 10.15.2. Any help or tip is welcome!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = 1
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab){
            CreateView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                    Text("Create")
                }.tag(0)
            ListView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "cloud")
                    Text("List")
                }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}


struct CreateView: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationView{
                List{
                    Text("Server")
                    NavigationLink(destination: CreateFirewallPolicyView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)){
                        Text("Firewall Policy")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Select the element you want to create", displayMode: .inline)
           }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                Section(header: Text("Servers")){
                    Text("Server 1")
                    Text("Server 2")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Firewall policies")){
                    Text("Firewall 1")
                    Text("Firewall 2")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("My virtual datacenter", displayMode: .large)
        }
    }
}



struct CreateFirewallPolicyView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    @Binding var selectedTab: Int

    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var allowed_ip: String = ""
    @State private var ports: String = ""
    @State private var description: String = ""
    @State private var selectedAction = RuleAction.allow
    @State private var selectedProtocol = NetworkProtocol.tcp
    @State private var rules: [Rule] = []

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Name of the firewall policy")){
                TextField("Nombre", text: $name)
            }
            Section(header: Text("New rule")){
                Picker(selection: $selectedAction, label: Text("Action")) {
                    ForEach(RuleAction.allCases, id:\.self) { fw_action in
                        Text(fw_action.name)
                    }
                }
                if (selectedAction == RuleAction.allow){
                    TextField("Allowed IP", text: $allowed_ip)
                    Picker(selection: $selectedProtocol, label: Text("Protocol")) {
                        ForEach(NetworkProtocol.allCases, id:\.self) { fw_protocol in
                            Text(fw_protocol.name)
                        }
                    }
                    TextField("Ports", text: $ports)
                }
                TextField("Description", text: $description)
                Button(action: {
                    if self.selectedAction == RuleAction.deny{
                        self.ports = ""
                        self.allowed_ip = ""
                        self.selectedProtocol = NetworkProtocol.any
                    }
                    self.rules.append(Rule(id: UUID().uuidString, protocol: self.selectedProtocol, port: (self.ports.isEmpty ? nil : self.ports), source: (self.allowed_ip.isEmpty ? "0.0.0.0" : self.allowed_ip), description: (self.description.isEmpty ? nil : self.description), action: self.selectedAction))
                    self.allowed_ip = ""
                    self.ports = ""
                    self.description = ""
                    self.selectedAction = RuleAction.allow
                    self.selectedProtocol = NetworkProtocol.tcp
                }) {
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Add new rule")
                    }.disabled(self.selectedAction == RuleAction.allow && (self.selectedProtocol == NetworkProtocol.tcp || self.selectedProtocol == NetworkProtocol.udp || self.selectedProtocol == NetworkProtocol.tcp_udp) && self.ports.isEmpty)

                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("Rules to add")){
                ForEach(self.rules, id:\.self) { rule in
                    Text("\(rule.action.rawValue.capitalized) - \(rule.source ?? "all") - \(rule.protocol.rawValue) - \(rule.port ?? "")")
                }.onDelete(perform: delete)
            }

        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Create Firewall Policy")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(
            leading:
                Button(action: {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Cancel")
                },
            trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    print("Create")
                }) {
                    Text("Create")
                }
                .disabled(name.isEmpty || rules.count == 0)
        )
    }

    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        rules.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

struct Rule:Codable, Hashable, Identifiable{
    let id: String
    var `protocol`: NetworkProtocol
    var port: String?
    var portFrom: Int?
    var portTo: Int?
    var source: String?
    var description: String?
    var action: RuleAction
}

enum NetworkProtocol: String, Codable, Hashable, CaseIterable{
    case tcp = "TCP"
    case udp = "UDP"
    case icmp = "ICMP"
    case tcp_udp = "TCP/UDP"
    case ipsec = "IPSEC"
    case gre = "GRE"
    case any = "ANY"
    var name: String {
        return "\(self.rawValue)"
    }
}

enum RuleAction: String, Codable, Hashable, CaseIterable{
    case allow
    case deny
    var name: String {
        return "\(self)".capitalized
    }
}
```

Comment: The `problem a)` is absent on Xcode 11.2.1

Comment: Thanks @asperi let's hope is just a bug.